# Datadog log remapper with change of value

Tags: datadog

I want to parse a log :

```
I1117 15:32:01.453645       1 secretproviderclasspodstatus_controller.go:222] "reconcile started" spcps="omy/dskjhf-kfkhdsfj-sdfjhdf-65c7989777-ktl6f-prd-hjgdsfj-secrets"
```

The first letter indicate the status :

- I -> Info
- W -> Warning
- E -> Error

It's not that hard to parse this log

```
{
   log_status : "I"
   ...
}
```

I can use the status remapper to indicate that log_status has to be used has status field.
But of course I, W or E have to be understood by datadog as Info, Warn or Error, how can I make datadog understand it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a category processor to your pipeline after the grok parser.

[image]
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/processors/?tab=ui#category-processor

Comment: Ah yes ! I missed the page, thank you !